# Removing characters from a URL field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user profile with an url field that shows their website. Right now it displays it like this: http://www.userwebsite.com

How can I remove the "http://www." part on my `show.html.erb` file, when displaying the user profile?

Answer (score 3):

You can either play string games or you can use the URI module:

```
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse("http://www.userwebsite.com")
url.host.split(".")[-2..-1].join(".")
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you know that you've only got the host at this point, not the scheme or any other noise, such as the post-host path, etc.

It's probably easier to just split the URL and do this stuff but you'll have more error handling and special case handling that way.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to 'uri'